# Cannot apply CSS in angular applicaton

Tags: css, angularjs

For some reason I cannot apply css to my image in angular app. i have tried:

```
<img ng-src="Images/{{Type.TypeImg}}" ng-click="GoNext(Type.TypeId)" ng-style="zoneicon" />
```

and

```
<img ng-src="Images/{{Type.TypeImg}}" ng-click="GoNext(Type.TypeId)" ng-style="border: 1px solid blue;" />
```

but neither worked

Comment: Why not just `style="border: 1px solid blue"`

Comment: Juan Mendes, that did not work either. Tried it

Comment: I find that hard to believe, can you post what you have tried? http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/HB7LU/23210/

Comment: I applied style to the image, not the div

Comment: It doesn't make a difference

Comment: Actually I just tried it again - applied style using style attribute and it worked. But I will need to add a class defined in my css instead of inline code. How can I do that?

Comment: If you look at the answer I provided, I also set a `class`, just like a `style`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the style is not dynamic, you can just use the regular style/class attributes. See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/HB7LU/23212/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}

.some {
    background-color: #aaa;
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" 
     style="border: 1px solid red"
     ng-style="{color: 'blue'}"
     class="some">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
<img ng-src="Images/{{Type.TypeImg}}" ng-click="GoNext(Type.TypeId)" ng-style="{'border': '1px solid blue'}" />
```

ng-style takes a dictionary (js object) instead of string.

So in the first example `zoneicon` must evaluate to an object

Comment: `ng-style` can also be an expression that evaluates to an object, so if `zoneicon` was defined in scope as some sort of object with style properties it could also be valid.

Comment: No need to say 'seems to', the docs are quite clear: ng-style takes an "expression which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: @paultrone yes, but an expression should be rounded by double braces, for this reason it appears to be more a class name

Comment: @abidibo i don't think it needs double braces, check this out: http://plnkr.co/edit/PrwxAUbGNJ9HqOv3LFWc?p=preview

Comment: @paultrone ok, I'm updating the answer

Comment: {border: '1px solid blue'} was what worked. Is there a way to apply a class instead of inline code?  ng-class="classname" does not work

Comment: @ElenaDBA that's what docs stand for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass